# Add a list in to a pandas data frame column

Tags: python, pandas

Hello guys I have this code:

```
check_df = pd.DataFrame()
check_df['item'] = ''
check_df['simillar_items'] = ''

for item in sorted(df_clean.ProductName.unique()):
    population = sorted(df_clean.ProductName.unique())
    check_df['item'] = [item]
    simillar = calculate_similarity(item,population,sensitivity = 85)
    check_df['simillar_items'] = simillar
```

I want to get a dataframe that looks like this:

```
item   simillar_items    
item a [Item C, Item B, Item G]
```

When I run the loop as shown above I get the following error:

```
Length of values (2) does not match length of index (1)
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary, which represents your data, then convert it into a dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create an empty dictionary
data = {
    'item': [],
    'similar_items': []
}

# Add data to the dictionary
for item in sorted(df_clean.ProductName.unique()):
    population = sorted(df_clean.ProductName.unique())
    data['item'].append(item)
    simillar = calculate_similarity(item,population,sensitivity = 85)
    data['similar_items'].append(similar)

# Convert the dictionary into a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then, you can find your data in the `df` dataframe.